# Why is Page_Load fired a second time after RequestUserAuthorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, dotnetopenauth

I'm testing the "OAuth/OAuth2/OAuthClient/Facebook.aspx" file from the DotNetOpenAuth.Samples solution.

here is the code (Simple authentication from Facebook directly in the PageLoad) :

```
namespace OAuthClient {
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.Facebook;
    using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

    public partial class Facebook : System.Web.UI.Page {
        private static readonly FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient {
            ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"],
            ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"]),
        };

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IAuthorizationState authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
            if (authorization == null)
            {
                // Kick off authorization request
                client.RequestUserAuthorization();
            }
            else
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var graph = FacebookGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);
                        this.nameLabel.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(graph.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the Page_Load is firing for the first time, authorization == null, so the client.RequestUserAuthorization(); call is executed, and then, Page_load is firing a second time.

Why ? I don't understand the mecanism.

I used fiddler to sniff the response sent back by facebook after "client.RequestUserAuthorization()", but it's always an empty body.

My final goal is to launch the authenfication process from a button. But when the "client.RequestUserAuthorization();" call is executed within a button, nothing is fired a second time... so authorization is always null.